# how to combine html drop down list with my MySQL database

Tags: mysql

Hi everyone I was wondering if it's possible to mix the html drop down list with MySQL database, for instance If I want to select year on a drop down list and that option is linked with my database

Comment: What language are you using? Are you making this in PHP, javascript, etc. Please add the appropriate tags and provide more information

Comment: @Nhlanhla Mavhetha its definitely possible but as Michael said you need to provide us with which language you want to do. However there are many examples online with which ever language you select

Comment: Might also help to provide a [mcve] of what you've tried so far, with an explanation of what doesn't work.